# Access multiple dictionaries in a file - Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, stream

I am very new to Json files. I have a json file with multiple json objects such as following:

```
{"ID":"12345","Timestamp":"20140101", "Usefulness":"Yes",
  "Code":[{"event1":"A","result":"1"},…]}
{"ID":"1A35B","Timestamp":"20140102", "Usefulness":"No",
  "Code":[{"event1":"B","result":"1"},…]}
{"ID":"AA356","Timestamp":"20140103", "Usefulness":"No",
  "Code":[{"event1":"B","result":"0"},…]}
…
```

I want to parse these json objects like a stream. The end game for me however is to create pairwise combinations of event1 and result. like so:

[AB, AB, BB],[11,10,10]

**What I know**:
The exact structure of the dict

**What I do not know**: How to extract these dict by dict to perform this operation.

**I cannot modify the existing file**, so don't tell me to add '[ ], and ','

Additional Help:

I might run into files that I cannot store directly in memory, so a **stream** solution is more apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing there is to feed the file stream into a custom generator, that would "pre-parse" the json objects. That can be done with some state variables counting somewhat naively the number of open `{` and  `[` - each time it reaches zero, it yields a string with a full JSON object.

I could not figure out your desired final intent from the example you provided. I suppose you have other dicts inside "code", and what you want in the end is a pair of the combined "event1, result" inside each "code" value for the outermost dicts. If it is not that, suit yourself to change the code.

(An ordered dict is good enough for storing the results you need - and you can retrieve the separate lists for keys and values if you need)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
import string
import sys

def char_streamer(stream):
    for line in stream:
        for char in line:
            yield char

def json_source(stream):
    result = []
    curly_count = 0
    bracket_count = 0
    nonwhitespace_count = 0
    inside_string = False
    previous_is_escape = False
    for char in char_streamer(stream):
        if not result and char in string.whitespace:
            continue
        result.append(char)

        if char == '"':
            if inside_string:
                inside_string = True
            elif not previous_is_escape:
                inside_string = False

        if inside_string:
            if char == "\\": # single '\' character
                previous_is_escape = not previous_is_escape
            else:
                previous_is_escape = False

            continue

        if char == "{":
            curly_count += 1
        if char == "[":
            bracket_count += 1

        if char == "}":
            curly_count -= 1
        if char == "]":
            bracket_count -= 1

        if curly_count == 0 and bracket_count== 0 and result:
            yield(json.loads("".join(result)))
            result = []




def main(filename):
    result = OrderedDict()
    with open(filename) as file:
        for data_part in json_source(file):
            # agregate your data here

    print (result.keys(), result.values())

main(sys.argv[1])
```